# Can I use jQuery .append() within content generated by previous .append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Within a form I have a section where I want the user to be able to generate between 1 and 5 pieces of content I'm calling *Block*s. Using jQuery I can add and remove these Blocks with no problems.

However, within each Block I want to be able to generate between 1 and 5 additional pieces of content I'm calling *Items*. I can't get this bit to work for the life of me.

When I click on the "Add Item" link, nothing seems to happen.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  //variables
  var blockContent = '<div><p>This is a block</p><div class="item"><a href="#" id="addItem">Add Item</a></div><a href="#" id="removeBlock">Remove Block</a></div>';
  var blockRows = 1;
  var blockMaxRows = 5;

  var itemContent = '<div><p>This is an Item</p><a href="#" id="removeItem">Remove Item</a></div><hr/>';
  var itemRows = 1;
  var itemMaxRows = 5;

  //add a block
  $("#addBlock").click(function(e) {
    if (blockRows <= blockMaxRows) {
      $(".block").append(blockContent);
      blockRows++;
    }
  });

  //remove a block
  $(".block").on("click", "#removeBlock", function(e) {
    $(this).parent("div").remove();
    blockRows--;
  });

  //add an item
  $("#addItem").click(function(e) {
    if (itemRows <= itemMaxRows) {
      $(".item").append(itemContent);
      itemRows++;
    }
  });

  //remove an item
  $(".item").on("click", "#removeItem", function(e) {
    $(this).parent("div").remove();
    itemRows--;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block">
  <hr/>
  <a href="#" id="addBlock">Add Block</a>
  <hr/>
</div>
```

Comment: The `Add Item` link in the appended block is not linked to any function, therefore clicking that doesn't do anything as you've never told it to do anything.

Comment: In addition, you have repeating IDs when they need to be unique.

Comment: I would use a button styled as a link for `addBlock` and not an anchor, because it's more semantically correct. It isn't navigating to anywhere, but does a local action on the page.

Comment: does the `Remove Item` link work? if so, attach with `.on()` instead of with `.click()`.

Comment: Thanks, Tsahhi Asher. I went back and changed the anchors to buttons, attached with .on() and used the button name as the selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this script for dynamically added html

```
  //add an item
  $(document).on('click', '.addItem', function(){ 

    if (itemRows <= itemMaxRows) {
      $(".item").append(itemContent);
      itemRows++;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I also had to make some changes to the //add an item section to be more specific so the itemContent did not get added to every Block. I ended up using $(this).siblings('div').append(itemContent); which, I'm sure, reeks of novice cludginess but at least gets the functionality I want. My next challenge is to figure out a way to re-instance the itemRows variable per Block. As is, it only allows 5 total items across all Blocks so I'm simply not incrementing itemRows for now as a work around.